# Can I use an external download manager with Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, download, download-manager

Can I use for example `axel` as the default downloader for *Google Chrome*?

Comment: Take your pick,  http://www.chromeplugins.org/chrome/list-of-download-managers-for-google-chrome/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Here's one download manager that works with Chrome:

http://flareget.com/

**Original Answer:** (Archive only, extension removed months after this was posted)

Install this extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mfjkgbjaikamkkojmakjclmkianficch

It integrates with most popular download managers.

Comment: This Chrome extension has been removed from the web store.

Comment: the link is dead, sorry

Comment: Yeah, it seemed removed from seb store as in other comment. It did work for me by the time the question was asked, and worked for the original poster of the question. There should be more similar extensions in web store though.

Comment: So, delete this answer

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Downloaders](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/downloaders/lfjamigppmepikjlacjdpgjaiojdjhoj) extension. It can integrate with dozens of different download managers, and it actually still exists!